Double audio output


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Hello
i am trying to have the same audio play on two usb earphones, i have tryed multiple adapters but nothing work, the software force me to choose between one of them, while failing to bypass this issue from a software perspective (i know windows can do this same result with an app, VoiceMeter, android refuse to do the same)
i am trying to make a hardware solution
can a parallel usb adapter work like this ? if yes, should i use some resistors to protect it ? where and how much mOhm ?

Sounds like a device that acts as a USB slave and provides USB hosting. Not sure if there's enough of a market for this to have attracted the up-front capital investment and on-going support. Perhaps search for a DIY project that does this?

Not sure why this is tagged with [tag:android].

I suppose you could do it with a computer that presents one USB port as an audio device, then buffers the data and sends it to two USB ports that speak to audio devices. You could devise some way of processing responses from the two output devices so that they can be resolved into communication back to the original computer (for example, there might be a USB headset, with microphone, connected at the same time as USB headphones). Which is just expanding on the the comment by periblepsis.

Am sorry i wasnt clear in my question. The goal is to use 2 usb earphones on an android smartphone. Sooo using a computer aint going to help unless for seting up some softwares, i know i can just plug the two earphones in one port each on a pc, and use voicemeter to mamage the output, but a phone dont have many ports, using a usb hub to plug both didnt work since only one of the earphones is working, i can switch between the two but i fail to make both work simultaniously

Each USB headset is a separate audio device. You need one USB adapter and split the audio into two non-USB headsets.
You cannot parallel two USB devices like that.

You would do this far more easily with a 2 channel headphone amplifier. They are not expensive. I just saw one with 4 channels and separate volume controls, very reasonable cost.
